# Rename table column in query as other column in other table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I've got a two tables with this structure:

TABLE A:

```
    s22129    |    s22130    |    s22121    |    other signals...    
   -----------+--------------+--------------+---------------------
    value1    |    value2    |    value3    |         ...
```

TABLE B:

```
    code    |    description
   ---------+---------------
   s22129   |    temperature    
   s22130   |     humidity
   s22121   |     pressure
```

I need to rename in a select the column names to the `description` in table B

Comment: This is not ideal table design for the A table.  The `code` should be a _column_ in the A table, not part of the column names.

Comment: You've got a problem - you're mixing metadata and data. SQL Server doesn't have strong support for queries that try to deal with both at the same time.

Comment: Edit the question add expected results too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` :

```
select b.code, aa.code_val as description
from a cross apply
     ( values ('s22129', [s22129]), ('s22130', [s22130]), . . .  
     ) aa(code, code_val) inner join
     b 
     on b.code = a.code;
```